# FullSimplify does not simplify involving `ResidueSum`

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, complex

Consider the following code involving `ResidueSum`:

```
$Assumptions = {a>0, k1\[Element]Reals, k2\[Element]Reals, k3\[Element]Reals};\


G[x_, m_, a_] = (-I (x+I a))^m;
ResidueSum[ {Exp[-I k1 x1] Exp[-I k2 x2] Exp[I k3 x3]    G[x1-x2,3,a] G[x3, 3, a]/( G[x1-x3,3,2a] G[x1,3,3a] G[x2-x3,3,a] G[x2,3,2a]  ) ,Im[x1]<0 }, x1] // FullSimplify
```

Then, the result is

```
-((I E^(-3 a k1 - 
      I k2 x2) (E^(
        a k1 - I (k1 - k3) x3) (a - I (x2 - x3)) (a^4 k1^2 + 
          2 a^3 k1 (-6 - I k1 x2) + k1^2 x3^4 + 
          2 a (3 x2 (-7 I + k1 x2) + (6 I + k1 x2 (6 + I k1 x2)) x3 + 
             k1 (-6 - I k1 x2) x3^2) + 
          2 x2 x3 (3 + k1 x3 (3 I - k1 x3)) + 
          x2^2 (-12 + k1 x3 (-6 I + k1 x3)) + 
          a^2 (36 + 18 I k1 x2 - k1^2 (x2^2 + 2 x2 x3 - 2 x3^2))) - 
       E^(I k3 x3) (2 a - I x2) (4 a^4 k1^2 - 6 a x2 (5 I + k1 x2) + 
          2 I a (12 + k1 x2 (6 I + k1 x2)) x3 - 6 x3^2 + 
          4 a k1 (3 + I k1 x2) x3^2 + 6 x2 x3 (3 - I k1 x3) + 
          4 a^3 k1 (3 - I k1 (x2 + 2 x3)) + 
          x2^2 (-12 + k1 x3 (6 I + k1 x3)) - 
          a^2 (-18 + 18 I k1 x2 + 
             k1^2 (x2^2 + 8 x2 x3 + 4 x3^2)))) Boole[
      Re[a] > 0])/(2 (2 a - I x2)^3 (a - I (x2 - x3))^3 (a - I x3)^2))
```

Even though I assumed $a>0$ at the beginning, the result involves unnecessary `Boole[ Re[a] > 0]`. I am planning to apply subsequent `ResidueSum` of the result with respect to `x2` and `x3`, but the unnecessary `Boole[ Re[a] > 0]` hinders this process.

How can I truly simplify the above expression, such that the resulting expression is manifestly meromorphic?

Note: I am using the Wolfram cloud (free version).

Comment: Sorry, but which version are you using? the code runs as expected in `13.2.0`

Comment: @bmf Thanks for your comment. I am using the Wolfram cloud (free version). Code runs as expected means that there is no redundant `Boole [ Re[a] >0]`, right?

Comment: yes, exactly. no `Boole [ Re[a] >0]`. it seems weird because the cloud should have the latest version. Can you try two things, please? One `Quit[]` and then run the chunk of code you presented here. If that does not work, run the code in the answer I provided and let me know - I will undelete it so you can have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to wrap the assumptions with `(Full)Simplify`

Note that there's another Boole statement in the resulting expression.

I am using

`"13.2.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)"`

```
G[x_, m_, a_] = (-I (x + I a))^m;
FullSimplify[
 ResidueSum[{Exp[-I k1 x1] Exp[-I k2 x2] Exp[I k3 x3] G[x1 - x2, 3, 
     a] G[x3, 3, 
      a]/(G[x1 - x3, 3, 2 a] G[x1, 3, 3 a] G[x2 - x3, 3, a] G[x2, 3, 
        2 a]), Im[x1] < 0}, x1], 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0, k1 ∈ Reals, k2 ∈ Reals, 
   k3 ∈ Reals}]
```

> [image: res]